# Close All Browser In Nsis

Tags: cross-browser, nsis

Making A Code Which Will Close All opened Browser in nsis.

```
var hadBrowsers
Function closeAllBrowsers
FindWindow $0 "IEFrame"
IntCmp $0 0 0 closeAll
FindWindow $0 "MozillaUIWindowClass"
IntCmp $0 0 0 closeAll
FindWindow $0 "Chrome_WidgetWin_0"
IntCmp $0 0 done closeAll
closeAll:
MessageBox MB_OK "Please close your browsers or press ok to close them all automatically"
;Closing all IE Windows
loop:
   FindWindow $0 "IEFrame"
   IntCmp $0 0 skipIE
   IsWindow $0 0 skipIE
   System::Call 'user32::PostMessageA(i,i,i,i) i($0,${WM_CLOSE},0,0)'
   StrCpy $hadBrowsers "1"
   skipIE:
   FindWindow $0 "MozillaUIWindowClass"
   IntCmp $0 0 skipFF
   IsWindow $0 0 skipFF
   System::Call 'user32::PostMessageA(i,i,i,i) i($0,${WM_CLOSE},0,0)'
   StrCpy $hadBrowsers "1"
   skipFF:
   FindWindow $0 "Chrome_WidgetWin_0"
   IntCmp $0 0 skipGC
   IsWindow $0 0 skipGC
   System::Call 'user32::PostMessageA(i,i,i,i) i($0,${WM_CLOSE},0,0)'
   StrCpy $hadBrowsers "1"        
   skipGC:
   FindWindow $0 "IEFrame"
   IntCmp $0 0 0 wait
   FindWindow $0 "MozillaUIWindowClass"
   IntCmp $0 0 0 wait
   FindWindow $0 "Chrome_WidgetWin_0"
   IntCmp $0 0 done wait
 wait:
   Sleep 100
   goto loop
 done:
 ;MessageBox MB_OK $hadBrowsers
 StrCmp $hadBrowsers "1" 0 +1        
    Sleep 2000
FunctionEnd
```

this is not working .

Giving me some error.

I am trying to make a code in nsis which will close all opened browser and reopen them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Answer

```
Section 
Execwait '"$SYSDIR\taskkill.exe" /F /IM chrome.exe /T'
SectionEnd
```

we can kill any task.

Comment: This is very unfair to user - add at least simple message box with yes/no option before closing chrome to save his work or he will hate you!

Comment: Yes, I will I was testing it on my PC only.